# DB2 for i series: passing table row as parameter

Tags: db2, db2-400

I've got a table with many columns:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY, F1 INT, F2 INT, F3 INT, F4 INT, F5 INT, F6 INT, F7 INT, F8 INT, F9 INT, F10 INT)
```

Then I've got a function that takes row-data and performs some type of operation. For the sake of this example, i just sum them up (not caring of null values).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ROWFUNCTION(ID INT, F1 INT, F2 INT, F3 INT, F4 INT, F5 INT, F6 INT, F7 INT, F8 INT, F9 INT, F10 INT) RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
RETURN F1 + F2 + F3 + F4 + F5 + F6 + F7 + F8 + F9 + F10;
```

Then I've got some sort of function that calls this row-level function for each record.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DOSOMETHING() RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL 
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE RES INT DEFAULT 0;

    FOR C CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE DO 
        SET RES = RES + ROWFUNCTION(ID, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10);
    END FOR;

    RETURN RES;

END
```

Now the question is this. Having a function with a parameter for each table column is cumbersome.
It would be nice to have a 'record type' that just correspond to the table columns. This way I could pass a single parameter to the function. Maybe I missed something, but I couldn't find any solution to this problem in DB2 for i series.
If this solution is not possible, are there any workarounds?

I considered passing the ID, that allows the function to identify and load the record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ROWFUNCTION(ID INT) RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA
FOR SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE WHERE ID=ROWFUNCTION.ID DO
    RETURN F1 + F2 + F3 + F4 + F5 + F6 + F7 + F8 + F9 + F10;
END FOR;
```

and the call would be:

```
...
SET RES = RES + ROWFUNCTION(ID);
...
```

Despite being almost exactly what i was looking for, this solution has the major drawback of generating a second access to the table for each record instead of using the data already retrieved by the main loop. The efficiency loss maybe negligible in most cases but in case we want also modify the records, having a double access to the table seems to add a unnecessary level of complexity. This is why I would welcome other solutions to this problem.

Comment: Perhaps a view with an extra column would be both a simple and effective solution, until you have an actual need in terms of performance.

Comment: A view? Can you explain what you are  talking of?

Comment: Just meant `create view youview as select a.*, f1+f2+... as sum_of_values from yourtable as a`, the sum of values is available everywhere the view is used, you can update it since there is no join, the only drawback is when you add a column to the table you have to recreate the view to have the new column available in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the ARRAY data type, if you operate with just a set of integers.

```
CREATE TYPE INTARR AS INT ARRAY[]
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_ARR (P_ARR INTARR)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
  RETURN (SELECT SUM (ID) FROM UNNEST (P_ARR) AS T (ID));
END
```

```
CREATE TABLE JUST_4_RES (A INT)
```

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_RES INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE V_ARR INTARR;
  
  FOR V_C AS 
    SELECT F1, F2, F3 
    FROM 
    (
      VALUES
        (1, 1, 1)
      , (1, 1, 1)
    ) T (F1, F2, F3)
  DO  
    SET V_ARR = ARRAY [V_C.F1, V_C.F2, V_C.F3];
    SET V_RES = V_RES + TEST_ARR (V_ARR);
  END FOR;
  INSERT INTO JUST_4_RES (A) VALUES (V_RES);
END
```

```
SELECT * FROM JUST_4_RES
```

| A |
| --- |
| 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zQUWE0mY)